# How to get higher directory folder in python project?

Tags: python

It drives me crazy so I decided to ask here. I need to save the generated txt file (from lower structures of the project), to folder which is the sibling of the parent directory. I have used variety of different code along with all possibiliteis given by os.path.join etc and still nothing.

My structure:

```
--reports
--parent folder
  --another folder
    --another folder
      -file.py
```

My lates code (based on string):

```
abs_dir = str(Path(__file__))
i = abs_dir.index("master")
self.new_dir = os.path.join(abs_dir[:i]+f"reports//log({self.date}).txt")
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/

Answer (score 0):

Use double dots (`..`), that will go to the parent directory

If you want to get to a folder in a parent folder

```
f1
  - file.py
f2
  - a.txt
```

you could just do `../f2/a.txt`

In your case, you would have to go 3 folders up: `../../../reports/log...`